Type annotation when using macros assert_eq! and vec! in Rust
Is it possible to give the compiler type hints in this example using only macros?
Using two macros assert_eq! and vec! compiler gives this error:
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/lib.rs:6:9
  |
6 |         assert_eq!(chop(&vec![]), vec![]); // error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type

Here is the example code (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=83886decff48ece2aca3bdb37f7f4d0e):
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_chop() {
        assert_eq!(chop(&vec![]), Vec::<&[u32]>::new()); // this works
        assert_eq!(chop(&vec![]), vec![]); // error[E0282]: type annotations needed
        assert_eq!(chop(&vec![1, 1]), vec![[1, 1]]);
        assert_eq!(chop(&vec![1, 2, 3, 4]), vec![[1, 2], [3, 4]]);
    }


    fn chop(rolls: &Vec<u32>) -> Vec<&[u32]> {
        rolls.chunks(2).collect()
    }
}


It might be interesting to see the expanded forms of these macros, this might clue us in to why the compiler is not able to infer types

Distilling the problem down gets you to this:
fn main() {
    let rolls: Vec<&[u32]> = vec![];
    if rolls != vec![] {
        panic!();
    }
}

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:3:14
  |
3 |     if rolls != vec![] {
  |              ^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `U`
  |
  = note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `&[u32]: PartialEq<_>` found in the following crates: `alloc`, `core`:
          - impl<A, B> PartialEq<&B> for &A
            where A: PartialEq<B>, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized;
          - impl<A, B> PartialEq<&mut B> for &A
            where A: PartialEq<B>, A: ?Sized, B: ?Sized;
          - impl<T, U, A> PartialEq<Vec<U, A>> for &[T]
            where A: Allocator, T: PartialEq<U>;
          - impl<T, U, N> PartialEq<[U; N]> for &[T]
            where the constant `N` has type `usize`, T: PartialEq<U>;
  = note: required for `Vec<&[u32]>` to implement `PartialEq<Vec<_>>`

The ambiguity lies not in comparing the Vecs but rather comparing their elements. The compiler is trying to satisfy &[u32] == _ where _ is some placeholder type you're asking the compiler to infer. However there are multiple types that _ could be, and thus it emits an ambiguity error.
You can keep the macro but give it a type hint like this:
assert_eq!(chop(&vec![]), vec![] as Vec<&[_]>);

Or potentially change your assert to assert!(... .is_empty()).

Didn't know that as functions as a type hint. Thanks

There's two ways to make a zero-length Vec using the vec! macro: the empty brackets you have above, or by specifying a value and a length of zero.
assert_eq!(chop(&vec![]), vec![[0]; 0]);


This solution is okay, too. But a little bit convoluted. thanks
